# Probability conditioning on $X= Y$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, radon-nikodym

Given a random variable $X\sim \text{Exp}(1)$, I would like to condition on the event that $$``\text{$X$ behaves like an $\text{Exp}(1/2)$ random variable}".$$
Is there a way to define this event and state this as a proper conditional probability?

I know the Radon-Nikodym derivative can be used to describe this, but that would require us to change the probability measure.

Is there a way to do this (maybe using the RN derivative?) as a conditional probability?

**Edit:** I changed the $\text{Exp}(2)$ to $\text{Exp}(1/2)$ from the original question, which is more related to what I am thinking about. I didn't realize that there is a big difference previously.

**Update:**
I think there is a partial answer from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195902/how-to-explain-connections-between-bounded-radon-nikodym-derivatives-convex-com).

Due to a [result](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/zabell82.pdf) by Diaconis and Zabell (Theorem 2.1 and the remark after):

> If $Q\ll P$ and their
> RN-derivative $\frac{dQ}{dP}$ is bounded, then there exists a
> probability space such that $P$ is a marginal measure and $Q$ is a
> conditional measure.

I wonder if there are more recent results that handle the case when the RN-derivative is unbounded?

In the same paper, there is also the interesting remark

> For example, no geometric distribution can be obtained from a Poisson
> distribution by conditioning, but any Poisson distribution can be
> obtained from any geometric.

But I do not quite see the reasoning.

Comment: What would it mean for a random variable to behave like it has a different distribution?

Comment: I was thinking just like conditioning on $X \geq 0$, and in this case, "$X = Y$" but $Y\sim \text{Exp}(2)$. Maybe there is no way to do this via conditional probability, I am just not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_0 \sim \mathrm{Exp}(2)$, and $X_1$ be an independent random variable with density

$$f_{X_1}(x) = 2(e^{-x} - e^{-2x}), \qquad x \in [0, \infty).$$

Also let $Y \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(\tfrac12)$, independently, and set $Z=X_Y$. You can check that $Z$ has density

$$f_Z(x) = \tfrac12(f_{X_0}(x) + f_{X_1}(x)) = e^{-x},$$

so $Z \sim \mathrm{Exp}(1)$, and $Z \mid \{Y=0\} \sim \mathrm{Exp}(2)$.

(More generally, you could apply [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).)

Comment: A quick follow-up question: Is there a similar approach like this if we replace the $Exp(2)$ random variable with $Exp(1/2)$ random variable? We cannot define $X_1$ based on the same formula as it could be negative.

Comment: Not by this method; rejection sampling requires the target density $f$ and proposal $g$ to satisfy $f/g \le M$ for a constant $M < \infty$. @Xiao

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether you had something like this in mind, but you can do the following:

Introduce another random variable $Y\sim \text{Exp}(1)$ independent from $X$. Then by symmetry since $\Bbb P (X=Y)=0$:
$$\Bbb P (X<Y) =\frac 1 2.$$
Also by symmetry
$$\Bbb P ( \min (X,Y) > t, X<Y) = \Bbb P ( \min (X,Y) > t, X>Y)$$
Consequently,
$$\Bbb P ( \min (X,Y) > t, X<Y) = \frac 1 2 \Bbb P ( \min (X,Y) > t)$$.
This yields
$$\Bbb P ( X > t\vert X<Y) = \Bbb P ( \min (X,Y) > t\vert X<Y) \\
= \frac{\Bbb P ( \min (X,Y) > t, X<Y)}{\Bbb P ( X<Y)} = \Bbb P ( \min (X,Y) > t)$$
Since the minimum of two independent exponential random variables is again exponentially distributed with rate equal to the sum of the previous rates you obtain
$$\Bbb P ( X > t\vert X<Y) = \exp (-2t).$$ This means $X$ conditioned on $X<Y$ has distribution $\text{Exp}(2)$.